# Scaling sliced images on a web site

Tags: css, scaling

I've been working with a graphic artist that is insistent on how his graphical representation of a web site looks is exactly how it should look on a web site, and that it should be scalable to any screen resolution that is used. He has merged too many layers, which is keeping me from being able to use many of the layers as elements. When explaining this to the graphic designer (who works for the client) and to his boss, they decided that they wanted the site sliced. I've sliced the image in Fireworks, and obviously, without any kind of scaling, everything is fine. I pulled all of the Table Tags (`<table>`, `<th>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, etc) out of the code and have been lining up the image elements. I set the main `<div>` to `95%`. I've tried using `max-size` on the images set at `100%`, I've tried `px` and `%` for `margin`s. Is there a way to truly scale this? Or is this an exercise in futility?

Comment: FYI. I was setting height in CSS to Auto. width was max-width: 100%

Comment: It sounds like they don't understand modern responsive/adaptive techniques. Or much about the code at all. You have my sympathy. In such (increasingly rare) cases I've occasionally simply set image sizes in HTML itself to a percent... and been honest about what I think, in a non-confrontational way.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Before you ask questions like this, make sure you've tried looking for similar questions on this website (using the search box in the upper-right corner of the page), and that you've looked for solutions on other websites, like CSS-Tricks and W3Schools. Most importantly, make sure you format your question properly. If some text in your question is meant to be code, enclose it in back ticks (`), accessible via the tilde (~) key on most keyboards.

Comment: Coding like its 1999... I feel for you.  Without seeing the code/images, it would be hard to give a clear answer.  Browsers generally do a poor job of scaling images (some do it better than others).